# Send response back to sender using servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a scenario where various JSPs hit the same servlet. And there is a filter for that servlet which checks for a consition. Based on that condition the response has to be sent back to the jsp from where the request came. The servlet has to perform the same functionality irrespective of the source which sends the request. How can i write a generic code to redirect the response back to the source jsp.

Comment: could you send the request to the servlet via Ajax and then you wouldn't have to worry about the JSP name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the name of your jsp as a request parameter to the servlet.

```
request.setParameter("param", "123.jsp"); (in jsp)
request.getParameter("param"); (in servlet)
```